# Fine-grained timer for VBScript performance measurements

Tags: vbscript, timer, benchmarking

I'm doing some performance measurements in VBScript. I want to measure how fast my algorithm performs

```
t1 = Now()  
doAlotOfWork ()  
t2 = Now()  
MsgBox "Operation took " & DateDiff ("s", t1, t2)  & " seconds."
```

This gives me the time in seconds. If one algorithm results in a 1 second execution time and another in 2 seconds, this will hardly give me any useful information. I need to blow up the problem size to something that takes a minute to execute.

Does anybody know of a way to do these kinds of measurements in VBScript, but then more fine-grained. Something that introduces milliseconds for example.

I have a feeling that there must be a solution in WMI.

Comment: You need to run your algorithms in a loop hundreds or even thousands of times. That not only compensates for a lower resolution timer, but also prevents random "noise" from clouding your findings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [VBScript Timer function](http://www.w3schools.com/VBscript/func_timer.asp) to get the elapsed time in milliseconds:

> The Timer function returns the number
>   of seconds and milliseconds, since
>   12:00 AM.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that. I chose "timer" as a tag, but did not have the wits to check the VBScript documentation for a function with that name.

Comment: Be aware that the resolution of the `Timer` function isn't exactly one millisecond.  I can't find any documentation on this, but experimentally on my Win7 64-bit computer, the resolution is ~8ms.  At work, on WinXP, it's about 15ms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in HP QuickTest Pro, here are two more methods that you are afforded:

Timers will give a result (in milliseconds) that you can store in a variable

```
MercuryTimers("timerName").Start
Wait 2
Msgbox "Time is ticking..."
MercuryTimers("timerName").Stop
Msgbox "Elapsed time is: " & MercuryTimers("timerName").Elapsedtime & " milliseconds"
```

Transaction times show up in the QTP results / report

```
Services.StartTransaction "transactionName"
Wait 2
Msgbox "Time is ticking..."
Services.EndTransaction "transactionName"
```